# ffmpeg - convert pcm audio to ac3 without changing the frame rate?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

I have PCM audio which has frame rate of `199.964 FPS (240 SPF)`. When I convert it to AC3 the frame rate changes to `31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)`. This causes sync issues and I dont want to convert the video again. So is it possible to change the audio frame rate separately.

Command used to convert to AC3

```
`ffmpeg -i out.wav -c:a ac3 -b:a 448k out.ac3`
```

Original audio info

```
Format : PCM
Format settings : Little / Signed
Codec ID : A_PCM/INT/LIT
Duration : 2 h 18 min
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate : 199.964 FPS (240 SPF)
Bit depth : 16 bits
```

Converted audio info

```
Format : AC-3
Format/Info : Audio Coding 3
Commercial name : Dolby Digital
Duration : 2 h 18 min
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 448 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Channel layout : L R
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate : 31.250 FPS (1536 SPF)
```

Comment: Audio doesn't have a frame rate. It's just not measured that way. idk where that info is coming from.

Comment: Most audio encoders operate upon a fixed no. of samples at a time. So, audio samples are chunked into frames and delivered to the encoder. Upon decoding, those many samples are emitted. That's the framing. AC-3 works with 1536 samples in a frame, as noted in the media info. For LPCM, the convention is 1024, however it can be set to anything. To the OP, this is not the reason for any sync issues.

Comment: @Gyan any idea what could be the reason for it being out of sync? both video and audio are in sync in the original file and there are no delays. But after converting the file and stripping both audio and video metadata the audio goes out of sync

Comment: Your command shows you converting a wav file, not a video file.